# Existe uma maneira confiável de testar a conexão com a internet?

Tags: c#, .net

Li sobre a função [`NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable(v=vs.110).aspx), porém ela não funciona no meu caso, já que preciso verificar se realmente há conexão com a internet. Li também sobre tentar acessar a página do [Google](http://google.com) por meio de um [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx), por exemplo, que julguei ser a forma mais confiável que encontrei, mas se a página estiver offline (<del>o que é quase impossível</del>), ele me retornaria sempre que não tenho conexão com a internet, quando no caso eu poderia ter.

Existe alguma maneira de garantir a verificação de conexão com a internet? Se não houver, qual seria a maneira mais confiável de testar?

Comment: Uma possibilidade é utilizar a classe [Ping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx) com os ips `8.8.8.8` e/ou `8.8.4.4` (servidores DNS do Google). Outras possibilidades (em inglês) no [*Superuser*](http://superuser.com/questions/769005/what-is-a-external-reliable-ip-address-to-ping-to-check-if-internet-is-available)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe uma "maneira correta", embora o uso das interfaces de rede possa ser realmente útil e válido, não é 100% confiável, uma vez que é possível que as interfaces de rede variem de usuário para usuário.

O que eu costumo fazer é uma "cascata" de tentativas.

- A primeira tentativa é através de uma DLL do Windows que é importada no código:

  ```
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll")]
  private static extern bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int Description, int ReservedValue);
  ```

Ai fazemos a chamada assim:

```
int desc;
hasConnection = InternetGetConnectedState(out desc, 0);
```

- A segunda forma é utilizando o `ping` do próprio Windows, mas note que é possível que o Ping possa não existir ou então falhar em determinados computadores (ainda sim é mais confiável que a listagem de redes)

  ```
  //Segunda verificação, executa ping
  hasConnection = (new Ping().Send("www.google.com").Status == IPStatus.Success) ? true : false;
  ```
- Ai em último caso utilizamos esse mesmo meio que voce usou:

  ```
  //Checa adaptadores de rede
  if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
  {
    //Busca todos os adaptadores de rede
    foreach (NetworkInterface network in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
      if (network.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && network.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel && network.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
      {
       hasConnection = true;
      }
      else
      {
       hasConnection = false;
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Ai acredito que a versão ideal seria encadear os três em um bloco de decisão e verificar um por vez caso o anterior não exista.

Comment: Infelizmente os testes de conexão de rede ainda dependem muito so SO :/ então nunca poderíamos ter 100% de certeza, mas criando uma cascata de possibilidades nós diluímos o erros entre eles... Não é 100% mas aumenta bastante a confiabilidade.