# Ping no servidor com C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, ping

Existe alguma classe do .Net com a funcionalidade de ping ? Tenho o IP do servidor em um atributo do tipo String e gostaria de pingar o servidor para saber se ele está online ou offline. Alguém conhece ?

Comment: Relacionada:[Existe uma maneira confiável de testar a conexão com a internet?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151278/28595)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe a classe Ping, exemplo de uso:

```
public static bool pingServidor(string nameOrAddress)
{
    bool pingable = false;
    Ping pinger = new Ping();
    PingReply reply = pinger.Send(nameOrAddress);
    return reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Existe essa classe [Ping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class PingExample
    {
        // args[0] can be an IPaddress or host name.
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions ();

            // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
            // but change the fragmentation behavior.
            options.DontFragment = true;

            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);
            int timeout = 120;
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (args[0], timeout, buffer, options);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
                Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
                Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
                Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
                Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Atualizando.
Existe um construtor mais simples para o `Send`: [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/yf697k33(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Caso queira vc pode colocar também um timeout para seus pings e ainda fazer validações para verificar se o texto informado é realmente um possível ip válido:

```
 public bool isIPPinging(string? ip,int timeout = 1000)
 {
   IPAddress iPAddressValid = null;
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip) && 
           IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out iPAddressValid) &&
           iPAddressValid != new IPAddress(0))
     {
        try
        {
          Ping myPing = new Ping();
          PingReply reply = myPing.Send(iPAddressValid, timeout);
          if (reply.Status != IPStatus.Success) return true;
          else return false;
        }
        catch
        {
          return false;
        }
     }
   else return false;
 }
```

> Referências:
>
> > [Ping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=net-7.0)
>
> > [IPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).